# Newton-Raphson on strictly convex function

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-analysis, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

Maybe someone can give me a hint here:

> question 1: Given a sequence {$x_n$} which is the Newton-Raphson sequence on some $f(x)$ s.t. $f(x)$ is strictly convex and $f'>0$. 
>   Let $\alpha$ be the unique root of $f$ (i.e $f(\alpha$) = 0).
>   For any $x_0$ initial guess,
>   prove that $\alpha < x_n$ **and** $x_n > x_{n+1}$.

I know that I should use the fact that for any given $x_0,x_1$ s.t. $x_0 < x_1, f'(x_0) < \frac{f(x_1) - f(x_0)}{x_1 - x_0}$, and although I can see the geometrical correctness instantly, I am having a hard time to prove it formally.

Appreciate your guidance,
Yotam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of convexity, the tangent $f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ is a supporting hyper"plane" and thus completely below the function. Which means that at the root of the tangent, the function value is above zero, positive. As $f$ is strictly increasing, this means that $x_1$ is right of the root with $f(x_1)>0$, independent of the position of $x_0$, if that is not already the root $α$. This property then also holds for all further Newton iterates.

As the tangent in $x_n$ is also monotonically increasing, the positive value $f(x_n)>0$ implies that the next iterate $x_{n+1}$ has to be left of $x_n$.

Comment: Why $f(x_n)>0$? could you please explain? if we take a case that $x_0<\alpha$ then $f(x_0)<0$ for all $n<k$ when $\alpha=x_k$. 
from the equation of Newton method if I understand why $f(x_n)>0$ it will imply $x_{n+1}<x_n$ since given $f'(x_n)>0$.
Futhermore, to prove $x_n>\alpha$ we can use the error: $x_{n+1}-\alpha$ = $1/2 \cdot (x_n-\alpha)^2\cdot \frac{f''(x_n){f'(x_n)}$. all the right value is positive then $x_n>\alpha$. correct?

Comment: @JohnD : Because as said, the tangent line is below the function. Thus where the tangent is zero, the function has to be positive. Which directly implies $x_1>α $ for any $x_0\ne α$ under the given assumptions on $f$. And also $x_n>α$ for all $n>0$. Because of the strict convexity, the tangent in $x_n$ only touches the function in $x_n$, the tangent root can never be a function root. There are no assumptions on the existence of a second derivative.

Comment: I got it, Thanks! Then only if our f is a twice differentiable function then is convex function if and only if its second derivative is non-negative there. Thats why I thought, $f''(x)>0$ and we can use it. Now it is understood! Thanks!

Comment: @JohnD : See the Rademacher theorem, every convex function is almost twice differentiable. But in general convexity is defined derivative-free via supporting hyperplanes or for scalar functions via mean inequality $f(\frac{a+b}2)\le\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2$.